# SQLAlchemy: exclude few columns during column reflection?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am mapping a table using declarative base and reflection. The db table has 1k+ columns, but I want to map only few hundred columns whose names are available via a sql.

Using reflection, I get the Column info in my event handler function, which allows me modify the Column's attributes but I am unable to skip the column from mapping.

```
def column_reflect(inspector, table, column_info):
   #...

class MYCLASS1(Base):
    __table__ = Table('MYTABLE1', mymetadata, autoload_with=myengine, autoload=True, listeners=[('column_reflect', column_reflect)])
```

Does SQLAlchemy support skipping certain columns while using reflection?

SQLA version: 0.83 and 0.9.0b1.

Comment: Cannot you use the `include_columns` parameter to `Table` constructor? Or do you actually perform the selection logic in your reflect handler?

Comment: van, your suggestion of include_columns worked. I was too much focused on the listener functions and missed seeing this simple option on Table().  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'van' answered my question so marking the question answered.
The solution was to use include_columns parameter on Table().